What's the best way to organize the content on this page? How do I place the different kinds of inputs and read-only values since there's so many
I'm redesigning a web form that users can use to create water compliance tests. The issue I'm running into is that there's a lot of information - both inputs and read-only fields that are derived from an input. What's the best way to organize this content on the screen? I have read that it's better to have a single column layout in web forms but I don't want to waste the width of the screen by having a single column. What's the optimal use of screen space in this case? I'm also wondering the best way to display read-only fields with input fields together. Any help is appreciated, thanks!
Here's a picture of the screen for reference: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZh2pF7h0Yz2FZWQH7JnUR_0bepVJqOQ/view?usp=sharing

Please share the image by pasting it in the question instead of its link.

I would suggest doing a Task Flow analysis for what your users are doing as they fill out the form. Are they sitting down with a sheet of paper that has all their input values? Are they in front of these values testing things and then entering the values into a tablet step by step.
What you want to do is to design a form that easiest for your users. Don't worry about optimizing for the width of a screen, remember the more info and fields displayed at once increases your users cognitive workload.

Thanks for the reply, I did a task flow analysis and most of these values will be input from a sheet of paper in front of them. I completely agree that this is a very information heavy screen but unfortunately, they will end up filling out most of these values. I did some wireframing and come up with a 3 column layout to make the content more manageable using good form design practices I could find online. Thoughts? https://drive.google.com/file/d/17LmJn0-XZXHRUAftjXDW4xzloANStPO9/view?usp=sharing
